Trace morphism in deligne/milne:s "tannakian categories".
Is there a connection between the trace morphism (1.7.3 on page 10 in https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc2022.pdf) and characters of finite groups?
I am also trying to understand why 1.7.4 on the same page (in ibid.) holds. Any clarification on this would be much appreciated.
I tried finding something more in Etinghof et al:s book "Tensor Categories" about this.
Would for example $\text{rank}(X) = \text{tr}_X(\text{id}_X)$ correspond to the dimension of a representation $(V, \rho)$ in $\text{Rep}_G$ in some functorial sense (i.e. as $\text{tr}(\rho(1_G))$)?
Perhaps I am wildly off.
Actually, $\text{rank}(X \otimes X') = \text{rank}(X) \cdot \text{rank}(X')$ is just an application of the first equation in 1.7.4.
Similarly, we have
$
\text{rank}(\mathbb{1}) := \text{tr}_{\mathbb{1}}(\text{id}_{\mathbb{1}}) = \text{id}_{\mathbb{1}}$ by the second equation in 1.7.4. This explains the equalities in 1.7.5.
Edit: I am mainly interested in understanding why 1.7.4 holds.

I believe there should be a connection — at least in the case of modular tensor categories, there is a functor between pointed modular tensor categories and metric groups. The bi-characters/quadratic-form on the metric group uniquely coincide with the MTC through this trace. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.00510

@AliasK  Thanks for the link!
